# rendering post with assigned tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, render

If I used this code to set up a tagging system for my app, how would I then render the posts with the tags I assigned to them. For instance if I assigned a sports tag to a couple posts, how would I then render all posts with the sports tag assigned to it

```
 rails g model tag name:string
 rails g model tagging article_id:integer tag_id:integer
 rake db:migrate

 class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :article
   belongs_to :tag
 end

 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :articles, :through => :taggings
 end

 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
   validates_presence_of :name, :content
   attr_writer :tag_names
   after_save :assign_tags

   def tag_names
     @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
   end

   private

   def assign_tags
     if @tag_names
       self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\s+/).map do |name|
         Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
       end
     end
   end
 end

 <p>
   <%= f.label :tag_names %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>
 </p>
```

Comment: isn't the answer is `tag.articles`?

Comment: would that render a post with a specific tag?

Comment: Similar to @Chris Mohr's answer, it would render the posts with the "sports" tag. Rails automatically build the correct SQL based on `has_many :through`. You may inspect what the sql is generated in the development log :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
# TagsController
def show
  @articles = Tag.find_by_name('sports').articles
end

# tags/show.html.haml
- @articles.each do |article|
  = render :partial => :article
```

Comment: what about if there were more than just one tag, for instance sports and politics etc.

Comment: You would likely use the tag.id in the show method. `@articles = Tag.find(params[:id]).articles` Link to a tag: `tag_url(tag)`.

Comment: would that be <%= render tag_url(tag), sports.articles %> in the view

Comment: The view would be the same as in the answer. To link to the tag's show action from another view, you would use the url helper like `tag_url(tag)` where `tag` is a Tag instance.  The url would look something like http://yourserver.com/tags/12 where `12` is the tag id.

Comment: Another alternative in the view is to pass the collection to the partial like: `render :partial=> article, :collection => @articles`

Comment: I just realized looking through my code I don't have a tags controller or a tags view. What I want to do is render the lists of posts with the tags in my posts view through my posts controller